# How do I make it so that files created in a directory have a certain group ownership?

Tags: linux, file-permissions, permissions

In a modern Linux distro, I want the files created under `/path/to/files` to have a default group of `mygroup`. It seems on some distributions this can be done by grpid, which doesn't exists on Ubuntu. What is the standard way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 9):

You just need to set the group ownership and then set the group setgid bit on the parent directory.

```
$ chgrp -R mygroup /path/to/mydir
$ chmod g+s /path/to/mydir
```

Comment: It seems this only changes the permission of new files to something like `-rw-r-Sr--` but the group is not changed.

Comment: @ubt The first command here sets the group of existing files and the directory. The second command changes the directory itself, new files created in the directory (because of the "setgid" bit on the group permissions) will inherit the group of the directory itself. So if the directory is owned by "mygroup" then new files will be owned by them as well (unless specified otherwise in the creation process).

Comment: Note that the second command also has to be recursive for this to work on the whole subtree, i.e. `chmod -R g+s /path/to/mydir`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `setgid` permission with

```
chmod g+s directoryname
```

Comment: Also needs to have the directory owned by the "mygroup" group, but close enough for a +1